# Does Mathematica always return a rational number in its simplified form?

Tags: arithmetic

If I enter: `1/RandomInteger[10^200]+1/RandomInteger[10^200]`
I get (instantly) an exact fraction. Is this fraction in simplified (reduced) form?  In other words is the greatest common divisor of the numerator and denominator equal to 1?.

Comment: Yes.   (And what does the reference to `RandomInteger` have to do with the fundamental question anyway?)

Comment: The function RandomInteger has nothing to do with my question.  My question is how does Mathematica simplify a fraction so quickly.  I thought simplifying the fraction would necessitate factoring the integers.

Comment: I strongly recommend you change your question title (which isn't a question anyway) to be relate to your actual question.  Future users will be very confused by your irrelevant reference to `RandomInteger`.

Comment: Now that I have thought better about it I see that we do not need to factor the integers (numerator and denominator) in order to simplify a fraction.

Comment: It is not necessary to factor the integers. Euclidean algorithm can computer the greatest common factor, then both the numerator and denominator divide the gcd. All the operations is only the division.

Comment: Note that if you would like it not to reduce the Rational, you can use ``Internal`RationalNoReduce`` (e.g. ``Internal`RationalNoReduce[2, 4]``). The lack of reduction is persistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, and you can also test it.

```
1/RandomInteger[10^200] + 1/RandomInteger[10^200] /. 
 Rational[a_, b_] :> GCD[a, b]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```